# Spring Lazy-init not working with @Resource injection

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, classnotfoundexception

I have an interface with real and mock implementation. for obvious reasons the mock implementation is not in the production classpath.
I inject the bean using:

```
@Resource (name="${myClient}")
```

I am using Spring MVC and injecting this into a `@Controller`.

In external configuration I set the actual bean name to use and bind it to 'myClient' parameter. The binding works and it tries to load the real implementation but also fails on ClassNotFound on my mock although marked as lazy-init=true.

I am using Spring 4.0.0.

I know this is expected when suing @Autowire, but with @Resource I don't expect it to try and instantiate all beans in spring xml.

Any ideas wha't going on?

Here is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [MyMock] for bean with name 'myClientMock' defined in URL [file:/C:/myProject/target/classes/META-INF/springContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyMock1
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1327)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:382)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:361)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:347)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:89)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
```

Comment: maybe attaching springContext.xml will be helpful to understand what makes this bean creation error.

Comment: Any idea where this references it´s come from? "MyMock1"

Comment: MyMock1 is my class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if you´re using Spring profiles, but it´s what we use here to initialize different beans per environment.
From Tomcat we spcecify which profile use, and in Spring we have configure something like this.

```
<beans profile="deployed-local">
    <util:properties id="propertyConfigurer" location="classpath:app.deployed-performance.properties"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.deployed-performance.properties,classpath:app.constants.properties"/>
    <import resource="spring/jdbc-config-test.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/contacts-config-deployed.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/security-config-local.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/clamAV-service.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/document-service.xml"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="deployed-prod">
    <import resource="spring/jdbc-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/contacts-config-deployed.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/security-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/clamAV-service.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring/document-service.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Although this would probably work, isn't it a bug that Spring initializes my bean although it shouldn't? The source of the problem seems to come from here:

Comment: I think it´s not an issue of Spring ut your implementation. I provide you this alternative since I think it´s more clear and elegant.